# passing Ref to another class as a parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

I need to pass a riverpod notifier provider from one class to another so I can update the state of the provider.

Here is what I mean:

```
class MainScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  static MainScreenState? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<MainScreenState>();
  }

  @override
  //MainScreenState
  ConsumerState<MainScreen> createState() => MainScreenState();
}

final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

String? userFName = "";
String? userLName = "";
String? userEmail = "";

Future<void> signOut() async {
  await auth.signOut();
}

class MainScreenState extends ConsumerState<MainScreen> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userFName = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).fName;
    userLName = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).lName;
    userEmail = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).email;
  }

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      body: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex]),
      drawer: SideDrawer(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)), <<<< ERROR HERE
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = value;
          });
          if (value == 3) {
            ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false);
          }
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: "Trxn"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Calendar"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "User"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}

class SideDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  SideDrawer(this.globRef, {super.key});

  Ref? globRef;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: (ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text("${userFName} ${userLName}"),
            accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser!.email ?? 'No Email Found'),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.add_business,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Add Company'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen(true)));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Add User'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  globRef.
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.calculate,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Mortgage Calculator'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const MortgageCalculatorScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                title: const Text('Log Out'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  signOut();
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I am getting an error when I try to pass the ref to the class SideDrawer.

Here is the error:

```
The argument type 'AlwaysAliveRefreshable<GlobalsNotifier>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<Ref<Object?>?>'.
```

How do I pass the notifier provider to another class so I can update the state?
Thanks

Comment: What does your `usersNotifierProvider` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `SideDrawer` class extends the `ConsumerWidget` type. Then the correct instance of `ref` will be available in the `build` method as a parameter.

Note also that there is a possibility of an error when you use `ref.read` in the `build` method. If suddenly your `globalsNotifierProvider` changes, the widget will not update and will use the old instance.

So use `ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider)` if you want to access the state and `ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)` if you want to access the notifier. This applies to both the `build` method and dependencies on other providers within the provider.